# Django formset if TOTAL_FORMS has different number than actual number of forms

Tags: django, django-forms

When dealing with dynamic formset, there are times when TOTAL_FORMS is greater than the actual number of forms. Also, this input TOTAL_FORMS can be modified easily by a user.
So for example, my input is

```
<input name='user-TOTAL_FORMS' type='hidden' value='5'/>
```

However, there are only 2 actual forms displayed.

In this case Django generates unwanted empty forms in formset.forms variable. And this creates a problem if there are any validation errors and form is displayed again. Page shows those unwanted forms. (In the example, only 2 actual forms should be displayed but since total count is 5, a user sees total 5 forms)

How can I remove these unwanted forms, update my total count and redisplay the forms with updated formset?

EDIT:
The challenging part is to update the indices as well when removing forms. So the total forms count match with the last form index.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's an old question and I am not sure if Django has changed much since. But the way I ended up doing it was to write a function to update formset data. The key here is to make a copy of the formset data (QueryDict) first. Here is the code:

```
def updateFormDataPrefixes(formset):
    """
    Update the data of the formset to fix the indices. This will assign
    indices to start from 0 to the length. To do this requires copying 
    the existing data and update the keys of the QueryDict. 
    """

    # Copy the current data first
    data = formset.data.copy()

    i = 0
    nums = []
    for form in formset.forms:
        num = form.prefix.split('-')[-1]
        nums.append(num)
        # Find the keys for this form
        matched_keys = [key for key in data if key.startswith(form.prefix)]
        for key in matched_keys:
            new_key = key.replace(num, '%d'%i)
            # If same key just move to the next form
            if new_key == key:
                break
            # Update the form key with the proper index
            data[new_key] = data[key]
            # Remove data with old key
            del data[key]
        # Update form data with the new key for this form
        form.data = data
        form.prefix = form.prefix.replace(num, '%d'%i)
        i += 1

    total_forms_key = formset.add_prefix(TOTAL_FORM_COUNT)
    data[total_forms_key] = len(formset.forms)
    formset.data = data
```

Answer (score -1):

Lol, It still old question, but real answer is "add `extra=0` attribute, because default `extra` definition is 3"

```
LinkFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    ParentModel, 
    ChildModel,  
    fields = ('price', 'deadline',), 
    extra=0
)
```

More documentation is available here : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/forms/models/#django.forms.models.inlineformset_factory